# How can I detect an error in AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery function, which is using AJAX to send the necessary information to run the respective script properly:

```
$("#changeUseridForm").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "API/root/users/changeUsername.php",
        data: {
        newUsername: ("#newUserid", this).val(),
        password: ("#retypePass", this).val(),
        xml: 1,
        },
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml){
            if($(xml).find("success").length > 0){
                alert("Username changed successfully!");

                $("#changeUserid").hide();
                $("#BackToMainMenu").hide();
                $("#MainPage").show();
                $("#AddLinkButton").show();
                $("#ChangeUserOptions").show();
                $("#ChangeUserDataButton").show();
                $("#ShowPosts").show();
            }
            else if($(xml).find("error").length > 0){
                alert("You have to fill all the fields!");
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

I have several functions like this one, running perfectly; this one isn't. I verified all my variables and scripts. They're spelled correctly. It doesn't reach to the script referenced. I think the AJAX code might have a problem, but I can't detect which error is. I tried to search it on my browser's web inspector, but I can't figure it out since the page is reloading for some reason that I don't know why. (Because this function doesn't have `window.location.reload()` in it anywhere.)

Comment: Look in the docs on `.ajax()`, you can specify an error handler function that gets details about what went wrong

Comment: @Pekka I'd post that as an answer. OP, if you're just debugging you can check the console/firebug for errors in http requests.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a `POST` request?

Comment: Probably not the source of your problem, but why use `("#newUserid", this).val()` instead of `("#newUserid").val()`?  IDs are supposed to be unique in the page, there is no reason to use a scope context with them.

Comment: Are you sure you want the URL for the ajax request to start with `API/root` instead of `/API/root`?  This makes it relative to the page you're on rather than relative to your site.

Comment: I used `(.. ,this)` to search the tag on the specific tag (in this case, I searched inside a <form> tag). You can use it, if you have many variables with the same name and/or for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set up a proxy or use firefox plugin to catch the get request(you can also use wireshark)

then you can see if there's a request to this page API/root/users/changeUsername.php
it is possible that this page API/root/users/changeUsername.php returns 302 redirect,

Check the http response of the GET Request and post it please

Comment: A Firefox plugin like Firebug?

Unfortunately, I have very different results in Firefox, compared with other test browsers (Safari, Opera).

It points to this error: `("#newUserid", this).val is not a function`

When, on the specified line, I have: `("#newUserid", this).val()`.

Also, I have this line in other functions and they run perfectly.

None of the browsers could run the script or return any results (HTTP) from it.

Comment: well i believe it needs the $ sign to identify as function try this for data <code> data: { newUsername: $("#newUserid", this).val(), password: $("#retypePass", this).val(), xml: 1, }, </code>

Answer (score 1):

Look in the [docs on .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you can specify an error handler function that gets details about what went wrong. That would be the first step.

You can also use [Firebug's or Chrome's "Net" tab](http://getfirebug.com/network) to monitor the request, and see what was returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect (debug) a lot of errors using firebug. In this case you can use the `net` tab and check `persists` to see what request is causing `reloaded` page.

[image]

Comment: I did it, but I didn't get anything about the script I want to execute.